# Android Location-Based App

Tags: android, location

I need a help with my app.
I've been trying yo build a simple location app. Therefore, I followed the Android Developer Training (http://developer.android.com/training/location/retrieve-current.html). However, I am stuck with the last part.
My app seems to crash whenever it hits this code,

```
mLocationClient.connect();
```

I've added permission and activated location service in my device. Can anyone help me?

This is my whole code.

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity 
implements
ConnectionCallbacks, 
OnConnectionFailedListener{
private final static int CONNECTION_FAILURE_RESOLUTION_REQUEST = 9000;

private LocationClient mLocationClient;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    mLocationClient = new LocationClient(this, this, this);
}

@Override
protected void onStart(){
    super.onStart();
    mLocationClient.connect();
}

@Override 
protected void onStop(){
    mLocationClient.disconnect();
    super.onStop();
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

public static class ErrorDialogFragment extends DialogFragment{
    private Dialog mDialog;
    public ErrorDialogFragment(){
        super();
        mDialog = null;
    }
    public void setDialog(Dialog dialog){
        mDialog = dialog;
    }
    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        return mDialog;
    }
}
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
    switch (requestCode) {
        case CONNECTION_FAILURE_RESOLUTION_REQUEST :

            switch (resultCode) {
                case Activity.RESULT_OK:
                break;
                default:
                break;
            }
        default:
           break;
    }
}

private boolean servicesConnected() {
    int resultCode =
            GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this);
    if (ConnectionResult.SUCCESS == resultCode) {
        Log.d("Location Update", "Google Play Services is available");
        return true;
    } else {
        Dialog dialog = GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(resultCode, this, 0);
        if (dialog != null) {
            //ErrorDialogFragment errorFragment = new ErrorDialogFragment();
            //errorFragment.setDialog(dialog);
            //errorFragment.show(getFragmentManager(), "Location Updates");
            //errorFragment.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "Location Updates");
        }
        return false;
    }
}

@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if (connectionResult.hasResolution()) {
        try {

            connectionResult.startResolutionForResult(
                    this,
                    CONNECTION_FAILURE_RESOLUTION_REQUEST);

        } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    } else {
        showErrorDialog(connectionResult.getErrorCode());
    }
}

private void showErrorDialog(int errorCode) {
    Dialog errorDialog = GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(
        errorCode,
        this,
        CONNECTION_FAILURE_RESOLUTION_REQUEST);
    if (errorDialog != null) {
        ErrorDialogFragment errorFragment = new ErrorDialogFragment();
        errorFragment.setDialog(errorDialog);
    }
}

@Override
public void onConnected(Bundle arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Toast.makeText(this, "Connected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

}

@Override
public void onDisconnected() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Toast.makeText(this, "Disconnected. Please re-connect.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

}
```

Comment: What is the error you get when your application crashes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you don't have Google Play Services installed.  You have the method servicesConnected(), but you don't use it.  You should wrap your call to mLocationClient.connect() in an if statement that checks servicesConnected().

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue and I had forgotten to add this in my manifest under application:

```
<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
           android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
```

Read [this](http://developer.android.com/google/play-services/setup.html) again for help.